# Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null, getUserMedia in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a little project and I need to get a webcam stream. I have read many articles and followed them but they have all come out with the same error.

Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null TypeError

```js
function James() {

  var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName('select');


    function handleError(error) {
      console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
    }

    function start() {



      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
      .then(function(stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
          video.play();
      }) .catch(handleError);

    }

    start();

  return (
    <div className="contentarea">
      <div className="camera">
        <video id="video" autoPlay></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default James;
```

Comment: you should use react refs in this case. with every rerender, the element actually changes, leaving the reference null. https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-createref-ea014ad09dba/

Comment: actually, since you are using a functional component, refer to this page on the react documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, it's generally not a good idea to use getElementById. Chances are in this case, that's running before the video element is even rendered, so you're storing null there.

Instead, you should be using a ref. Something like `const video = useRef()` and then setting `ref={video}` on your video element. Then you can use `video.current` to get a reference to the video element at any time, without worrying about rendering issues.